# undefined reference to `sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()' in eclipse cpp connection

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse

My cpp program worked fine in terminal and gave output also.It was run using:

```
g++ cipher.cpp -lmysqlcppconn
```

But when i tried the same in eclipse it is showing the below error?

```
 12:07:07 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for   project cipher ****
 make all 
 Building file: ../src/cipher.cpp
 Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
 g++ -I../usr/include/cppconn -I../usr/include -I/usr/include  /boost -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlclient -MMD -MP -MF"src/cipher.d" -MT"src/cipher.d" -o "src/cipher.o" "../src/cipher.cpp"

/root/Downloads/cipher/Debug/../src/cipher.cpp:528: undefined reference to `sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cipher] Error 1

11:54:39 Build Finished (took 472ms)
```

The program header portion includes

```
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include "mysql_connection.h"
```

using namespace sql::mysql;

The options -lmysqlcppconn and -lmysqlclient are included in project->properties->c/c++Build->Settings->miscalleneous->other flags

Eclipse IDE Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

what all "includes" and "libraries" are to be specified in eclipse "path and symbols"?

I have gone through answers of similar queries but they didnt helped me.

I am working on centos6.6